# I got a pokemon through trade but its in another language

Tags: pokemon-series

I've been playing Pokemon for a very long time and I got a level 100 pokemon from a trade and its level 100 last year. I know I cant evolve it but I'm really tired of it's name being in Japanese. I've tried for a while to ignore it but it's really getting annoying. I have no idea who traded it to me so I cant ask them to trade back or anything. I do love this pokemon but I dislike how I cant see its name in english. At the moment, I cannot trade it with anyone for the exact pokemon because of WiFi problems nor would I anyway. Its a level 100 Quilava for Pokemon X. Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 3):

Japanese Pokemon stay Japanese unless the original trainer manually names him.

The best that you can do is put him up on the wonder trade with a message like "English Plz", and set your desired level to 91+. You might get one that you need to level a bit, but that's generally worth it.

My favorite method is to breed the Pokemon. The child Pokemon will be in English, and you have fine control over stats and breeding moves. The downside is that you start at level 1, but you can level fairly quick in late game with exp share.

Comment: It's worth to remember that when you evolve a foreign pokemon it will "translate" its name in your current language, but he can't because of its level.